# Там половина софта пиратская или пиратского?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование, смысл

*Там половина софта пиратск**ая*** или *пиратск**ого**?*
Если сказать, что половина от всего софта там — это пиратский софт.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Берем для примера яблоко, и включаем логику.

Половина красного яблока (в постпозиции: половина яблока красного) — это означает, что **всё** яблоко красное (то есть весь софт пиратский), и где-то там имеется его половина.

Половина яблока [была, есть] красная — это означает, что одна половина красная (пиратская), а вторая — другого цвета (легальная).
Это наш случай: *там половина софта пиратская.*

Comment: Эх, Римма, неправильный вывод, не стоило проводить аналогию с яблоком. Придётся дать свой ответ. Но выбрали вы лучший вариант из предложенных.

Answer (score 0):

Глубокий и непростой вопрос.

**Обоснование первого варианта**

```
Там половина софта пиратская.
```

Здесь стандартная структура предложения, таких можно встретить миллион и в обосновании она не нуждается. `пиратская` здесь характеристика `половины софта` и входит в сказуемое. В других примерах *пиратский* и *пиратского* характеризуют не *половину софта*, а класс софта вообще.

**Обоснование второго варианта**

Рассмотрим, очевидно, корректное безличное предложение

```
Пиратского добра там лежало половина корабля.
```

И проведем цепочку выводов

```
Половина корабля там было пиратского добра.
Половина софта там - пиратского софта.
Половина софта там - пиратского.
```

**Обоснование третьего варианта**

```
Половина софта там - пиратский.
```

Получается он так

```
Половина добра там - пиратский софт
Половина софта там - пиратский
```

Отметим, что в последних двух вариантах ставится тире, поскольку в них опущено существительное `софт`. В первом варианте тире не нужно, так как там ничего не опускается.

Comment: М-м... *Половина софта там - пиратский.* Половина (ж. р.) не может быть пиратский (м. р.).

Comment: Я ведь объяснил. Половина добра там - пиратский софт. Теперь просто опускаем существительное софт. Предложение остается грамматически корректным

Comment: Но вообще, пропуск звучит не так. Ответ не годится!

Comment: Для тех, кто минусует, хотелось бы задать вопрос: "половина золота там - краденое" вам кажется жизнеспособной фразой? Почему в таком случае вы считаете что "половина софта там - пиратский" неверная фраза, если она получена аналогично с точностью до рода существительного? Ответ автора логичен, содержит опровергаемые выводы, которые логически никто не опроверг. Очень странно что этот ответ не является основным.

Comment: Ну, "краденное" может выступать в роли "существительного". Например "Краденное лежало на столе", чего не скажешь о "пиратский". Но в целом, да. Расчет был на эту макроформулу A - B. Типа как в "Он ушел - глупый" итп

Comment: *Рассмотрим, очевидно, корректное* — думаю, что там не вводное слово, по аналогии с "явно корректное", и в структуру оно не вклинивается. Примеры из Нацкорпуса: *Мне кажется, что критика очевидно позитивных вещей, скажем благоустройства, ― это именно политика. Сциентизм, при ближайшем рассмотрении, оказывается очевидно ошибочным. Скажем, тексты стали очевидно длиннее, а дыхание их вернулось к тому, жившему в стихах прежних.* Далеко не с каждым прилагательным так можно.

Comment: Согласен только с третьим вариантом. 1) Так не говорят. Порой могут охарактеризовать половину — например, когда речь о чём-то целом, но не здесь. Скажут так: *Половина софта там — пиратский.* 2) Нельзя просто пропускать глагол, он должен восстанавливаться из предыдущей части: *Половина софта там было лицензионного, а вторая половина — пиратского.* Но проблемы со стилистикой.

Comment: Насчет "очевидно" вы интересно подметили. Нацкорпус подтверждает. Однако темп произношения там, очевидно , другой, нежели у "явно". Он ближе к предикативу очевидно/понятно, а не к наречию: "Рассмотрим, понятно, корректное предложение." Предикативные вводные часто бывают неперестановочными.

Comment: Вводное (с паузами) там не очень звучит — наверно, из-за того, что перед прилагательным, которое допускает вариант без запятых. А с наречием так: *Это предложение (какое?) очевидно корректное.*

Comment: @user190920, заметьте, что я написал "краденое", а не "краденное". Тут есть довольно существенная разница. "Он ушёл - глупый" - это совершенно иная фраза: здесь уже есть глагол, в то время как во фразе "Половина софта там - пиратский" глагол опущен.

Comment: Давайте восстановим глагол, cохраняя при этом структуру СИС. "Половина софта там лежал пиратский.". Нормальная ли это фраза?

Comment: Если сказуемое — прилагательное, то тире перед ним не обязательно.

Answer (score 0):

Софт — это программы. Лучше звучит так (вариант правки):
*Там половина программ пиратские.*
Похожие примеры из Нацкорпуса:
*Половина застав ― таджикские.

Половина квартир заняты.*

Согласовывают с половиной, когда речь о чём-то целом:
*Половина палки белая.

Половина яблока красная.*

"*Половина софта пиратская*" звучит так, что это что-то цельное, а это ведь отдельные программы.

В случае с софтом скажут так:
*Там половина софта пиратский.*
Это называется "согласование по смыслу".
http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/64-bolshinstvo

Вот похожий пример:
*Там половина металла драгоценный.*

Для родительного обычно нужна связка, также для звучания важен порядок слов:
*Пиратского там было половина софта.*
Но при таком порядке и без "было" звучит:
*ПирАтского там — половина софта.* || Тире в связи с инверсией и логическим ударением.

Comment: Софт это неисчислямое существительное в отличие от программ. Дальше можно не читать.

Comment: Да понятно, то как дополнение — вариант получше и просто о факте нестандартного согласования.

Comment: Связка быть в настоящем времени опускается. Так как "Там половина софта есть пиратского" - явно не звучит. Да и не связка это. Полноценный глагол.

Comment: В настоящем времени так не говорят (без связки). Так связка вроде бы всегда является глаголом.

Comment: Но глагол не всегда связка. В нашем случае он не связка. Ибо связка всегда включается в сказуемое вместе с именительным падежом именной части. А у нас родительный.

Comment: Назвал связкой, потому что стыкует (связывает) элементы грамматически.

Comment: Ну ладно, при таком порядке и без "было" звучит.

Comment: *Это называется "согласование по смыслу".* Но ведь в ссылке речь идет о сказуемых, а у нас — определение. Вопрос, собственно, только в том, к какому из существительных его прицепить, чтобы обеспечить нужный автору смысл.

Comment: По ссылке конкретно такого, к сожалению, нет, но оно похоже — определение является сказуемым. Согласуем не с подлежащим ("половина"), а с примыкающим к нему существительным ("софт"), которое важнее в плане смысла. Не уверен, про это ли вы спрашивали (*к какому из существительных его прицепить*).

Comment: Ссылка не подходит в любом случае. Там немного о другом говорится. Я тоже начинал с анализа того текста. Там говорится о множественном числе, а у нас неисчисляемое подлежащее. "Большинство собак проголосовали" - возможно. "Большинство фауны проголосовали" - невозможно.

Comment: Просто говорю о согласовании по смыслу, а там про него, поэтому решил добавить ссылку.